# To make an dynamic element selectable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, selectable

I am trying to make Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3 selectable.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
   <ul id="outerUL">                   //static 
       <li id="outerLI">              //dynamic
           <ul id="innerUL">          //dynamic
              <li>Item 1</li>         //dynamic
              <li>Item 2</li>         //dynamic
              <li>Item 3</li>         //dynamic
           </ul>
       </li>   
   </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#outerUL").delegate('li','click',function(event) {
        $(this).selectable();
});
```

I am not able to find out the error.

Comment: What jQuery version do you use?

Comment: y dont u just disable and enable it on the ul

Comment: delegate is deprecated. you should use on

Comment: @bagonyi --jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: @DEV Then you have to change your `.delegate` to `.on` to work. see the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cross check if you have the proper verison of jQuery and download it from [here](http://jqueryui.com/)

The problem with the code

```
$("#outerUL").delegate('li','click',function(event) {
    $(this).selectable();
});
```

is that :

```
$(this).selectable();
```

will be called only when you click on some `li child` under `outerUL`. So your first click will not select any element rather it will just make the elements select ready.

Second problem is in this html snippet:

```
 <ul id="outerUL">                   //static 
   <li id="outerLI">              //dynamic
       <ul id="innerUL">          //dynamic
          <li>Item 1</li>         //dynamic
          <li>Item 2</li>         //dynamic
          <li>Item 3</li>         //dynamic
       </ul>
   </li>
```

According to your javascript code, every element which is a children of `#outerUL` should be selectable. So the first time any children of `#outerUL` is clicked,  `$(this).selectable();` statement will be called which will make the child `outerLI`selectable. On the subsequent clicks, jQuery's `selectable()` function will be called and it will select the full `outerLI` element.

I think this should solve your problem:

```
$(function () {
$("#innerUL").selectable();
});
```

It will make only the children of `#innerUL` selectable.

Comment: Thank you sir for making me clear...This code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**jQuery on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$(document).on('click','#outerUL li',function(event) {
    $(this).selectable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) you can read:

> *As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method*

You should use **`jQuery.on()`**

```
$("#outerUL").on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    $(this).selectable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

Or [Read Here](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/). Hope you like!

Answer (score 0):

you dont' need any function just check this one ***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VLE5P/)***

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable();
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#selectable').append('<li class="ui-widget-content">XXX</li>')
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="ADD" />
```